# Systrace no longer works on Nexus 6 in Marshmallow because of SELinux? Has anyone got it working again?

Tags: android, selinux, systrace

I used to be able to run systrace on my Nexus 6, but recently it stopped working (probably after one of the recent monthly updates): systrace hangs trying to download the trace off my device.

In `adb logcat`, I see a bunch of lines like

```
05-26 14:57:08.567  4933  4933 W <my.app.package>: type=1400 audit(0.0:23388710): avc: denied { getattr } for comm=66627379737472616365206E6F7469 path="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace" dev="debugfs" ino=4158 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I know systrace uses `debugfs`, and this appears to be a SELinux permission issue (see https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate.html). Has anyone got this working again?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Debugfs has a lot of deangerous bits in it, hence the split to tracefs. For more information these articles are handy:

- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=TraceFS-Linux-Tracing-FS
- https://lwn.net/Articles/630526/

in system/sepolicy on AOSP, one can find neverallows on this:

```
96b1c9ca (Nick Kralevich 2015-12-17 16:38:21 -0800 564) neverallow { domain -init -system_server -dumpstate } debugfs:file no_rw_file_perms;
```

As well as read for untrusted_app (which is covered by the above and seems superfluous):

```
$ git blame -L106,106 untrusted_app.te
96b1c9ca (Nick Kralevich 2015-12-17 16:38:21 -0800 106) neverallow untrusted_app debugfs_type:file read;
```

By the way, if you get hex-encoded comm fields, one can decode them like so, using Python:

```
'66627379737472616365206E6F7469'.decode('hex')
'fbsystrace noti
```

Comment: This begs the question: if debugfs was deliberately turned off, and systrace is still supported, why isn't systrace using tracefs? Is the OP doing something wrong, or is systrace simply broken on the currently-shipping Nexus 6 software?